# Configuring URI prefix for REST webservice in dropwizard

Tags: uri, dropwizard

I am developing a `REST API` using dropwizard. The `resource` can be accessed using `https://<host>:port/item/1`. As it can be seen there is no `URI` prefix. If I have to configure a `URI` prefix what needs to be done. Can it be configured in `yaml` configuration file?
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes the URI prefix a.k.a root path can be configured in YAML. You could use the simple server factory configuration. It's simple, add these two lines in your YAML. I've used 'api' as the prefix. You can replace it with the URI prefix you want.

```
server:
  rootPath: '/api/*'
```

A slightly more elaborate server configuration looks something like this,

```
server:
  adminConnectors:
    -
      port: 18001
      type: http
  adminContextPath: /admin
  applicationConnectors:
    -
      port: 18000
      type: http
  rootPath: /api/*
  type: default
```

You can refer to this example https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/example.yml for server and other configuration details.

It's also a good idea to go through this if you are just getting started with dropwizard http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/getting-started.html